# Combine almost identical dictionary value lists together per key

Tags: python, json

I have an input file like this:

```
structureId chainId resolution  uniprotAcc  structureMolecularWeight
101M    A   2.07    P02185  18112.8
102L    A   1.74    P00720  18926.61
103D    A                   7502.93
103D    B                   7502.93
103L    A   1.9     P00720  19092.72
103M    A   2.07    P02185  18093.78
104L    A   2.8     P00720  37541.04
104L    B   2.8     P00720  37541.04
104M    A   1.71    P02185  18030.63
104M    A   3.1     P09323  2312.2
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
structureId chainId resolution  uniprotAcc  structureMolecularWeight

101M    A   2.07    P02185  18112.8
102L    A   1.74    P00720  18926.61
103D    A                   7502.93
103D    B                   7502.93
103L    A   1.9     P00720  19092.72
103M    A   2.07    P02185  18093.78
104L    A,B 2.8     P00720  37541.04
104M    A   1.71    P02185  18030.63
104M    A   3.1     P09323  2312.2
```

i.e if col 'uniprotAcc' is the same for col 'structureId'; to combine them.

I wrote this code:

```
import sys

set_of_ids = list(set([line.strip().split('\t')[0] for line in open(sys.argv[1])]))

master_dict = {}
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
    if split_line[0] not in master_dict:
        master_dict[split_line[0]] = [split_line[1:]]
    else:
        master_dict[split_line[0]].append(split_line[1:])

print(master_dict)
```

which combines the data, so the key is the structureID and the values are a list of rows the structureId is involved in:

```
{'structureId': [['chainId', 'resolution', 'uniprotAcc', 'structureMolecularWeight']], '101M': [['A', '2.07', 'P02185', '18112.8']], '102L': [['A', '1.74', 'P00720', '18926.61']], '103D': [['A', '', '', '7502.93'], ['B', '', '', '7502.93']], '103L': [['A', '1.9', 'P00720', '19092.72']], '103M': [['A', '2.07', 'P02185', '18093.78']], '104L': [['A', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04'], ['B', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04']], '104M': [['A', '1.71', 'P02185', '18030.63'], ['A', '3.1', 'P09323', '2312.2']]}
```

I'm just stuck on one small thing, I know how to iterate through the dict:

```
for k in master_dict:
    for each_list in master_dict[k]:
```

I'm just stuck on the very next line, how to say 'combine the lists that are identical except for their 1st (assuming list is starting at 0) item.

i.e. so turn:

```
104L    A   2.8     P00720  37541.04
104L    B   2.8     P00720  37541.04
```

into:

```
104L    A,B   2.8     P00720  37541.04
```

I'm probably making it sound more complicated than it is, basically, for the rows in my table, if the only difference, per structureID and per uniProtacc, is the chainID column, combine the chainID columns.

Edit 1: Issue with answer below?

Say for example, this was the data:

```
structureId chainId resolution  uniprotAcc  structureMolecularWeight
6YC3    A   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39
6YC3    B   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39
6YC3    C   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39
6YC3    D   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39
6YC3    E   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39
6YC4    A   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86
6YC4    B   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86
6YC4    C   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86
6YC4    D   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86
6YC4    E   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86
```

So then the output should be:

```
6YC3 A,B,C,D,E 2.0 N0DKS8 181807.29
6YC4 A,B,C,D,E 2.6 N0DKS8 174142.86
```

Whereas the output from the code below is:

```
['6YC3', 'B,B,C,D,E,A,B,C,D,E', '2.0', 'N0DKS8', '181807.39']
```

Edit 2: To avoid issue above, I made a column that combined the UniProt accession and structureID:

```
structureId chainId resolution  uniprotAcc  structureMolecularWeight    newcode
6YC3    A   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39   N0DKS8_6YC3
6YC3    B   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39   N0DKS8_6YC3
6YC3    C   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39   N0DKS8_6YC3
6YC3    D   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39   N0DKS8_6YC3
6YC3    E   2.0 N0DKS8  181807.39   N0DKS8_6YC3
6YC4    A   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86   N0DKS8_6YC4
6YC4    B   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86   N0DKS8_6YC4
6YC4    C   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86   N0DKS8_6YC4
6YC4    D   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86   N0DKS8_6YC4
6YC4    E   2.6 N0DKS8  174142.86   N0DKS8_6YC4
```

and then I just replaced the line in the code:

```
idx_uniprotAcc = headers.index("uniprotAcc") #to...
idx_uniprotAcc = headers.index("newcode")
```

When I run the exact same code as below, with just that one line changed, the output is:

```
['6YC3', 'B,B,C,D,E', '2.0', 'N0DKS8', '181807.39', 'N0DKS8_6YC3']
['6YC4', 'A,B,C,D,E', '2.6', 'N0DKS8', '174142.86', 'N0DKS8_6YC4']
```

Why is the first row returning 'B,B,C,D,E' and not 'A,B,C,D,E'. I think it's something to do with iterating over data[1:]?

Comment: How can we know from which column the 7502.93 belongs to ? (line 3 and 4)

Comment: I'm terribly sorry that was my mistake when I was trying to write out a simple example, i've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the following approach:

1. Open the file and read all the lines. To do that, we can use [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). It returns all the lines as a `list`. (For more detail, this [tuto](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) explains how to use it).

   1. On each line, we apply [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/string.html#string.strip) to clean the string.
   2. Now we have a line, we want to extract the value from each columns. To do that, we will **split** the string according the spaces. However, the number of spaces between the values might change so we will use a *regex* with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. The [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) method lets split according a regex. The pattern used is  `\s+` where `\s` stands for *space* and `+` means *one and more*.

   The first step can be summed up in the following two lines:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    data = [re.split(r'\s+', line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
```

2. Select the headers with `headers = data[0]` as it's the first line
3. Iterate over all the lines. We use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to have the current index (and deduce the previous line).

   - If the current and previous line have the same `uniprotAcc`: we update the last output line by adding the current `chainId`
   - Else: we add the current line to the output

---

*Full code*

```
import re

# Read file
with open("data.txt") as f:
    data = [re.split(r'\s+', line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
print(data)


# Select headers
headers = data[0]
# Get index columns if not known
idx_uniprotAcc = headers.index("uniprotAcc")
idx_structureId = headers.index("structureId")
idx_chainId = headers.index("chainId")
# Remove header line
data = data[1:]

# In any case, we can add the header and first line to the output
out = [headers, data[0]]
print(out)
# Iterate over the lines starting at the second one
for i, line in enumerate(data[1:]):
    # Get preivous line (i start at 0 but data is started at first line)
    prev_line = data[i]

    # print("prev:    ", prev_line)
    # print("current: ", line)

    # Check line are the same and they both have all the values
    # Here you can add as any column check as you want 
    # (here I just added one on "structureId" as this seems to match the output
    #  but to be sure, it's may be better to check all the columns)
    if len(line) == len(headers) and \
            len(prev_line) == len(headers) and \
            line[idx_uniprotAcc] == prev_line[idx_uniprotAcc] and line[idx_structureId] == prev_line[idx_structureId]:
        # Merge current with previous output line
        out[-1][idx_chainId] += ",{}".format(line[idx_chainId])
    else:
        # Line is added
        out.append(line)

[print(x) for x in out]
# ['102L', 'A', '1.74', 'P00720', '18926.61']
# ['102L', 'A', '1.74', 'P00720', '18926.61']
# ['103D', 'A', '7502.93']
# ['103D', 'B', '7502.93']
# ['103L', 'A', '1.9', 'P00720', '19092.72']
# ['103M', 'A', '2.07', 'P02185', '18093.78']
# ['104L', 'A,B', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04']
# ['104M', 'A', '1.71', 'P02185', '18030.63']
# ['104M', 'A', '3.1', 'P09323', '2312.2']
# ['6YC3', 'A,B,C,D,E', '2.0', 'N0DKS8', '181807.39']
# ['6YC4', 'A,B,C,D,E', '2.6', 'N0DKS8', '174142.86']

# Export in text file
# with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
#     f.writelines("%s\n" % "  ".join(x) for x in out)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for not just the code, but the explanation

Comment: I think I have realised an issue with this, if I could get your opinion on whether I'm right or wrong. But also, I can try to fix this myself, updating question above to show issue.

Comment: I see, the grouping is done only if all others columns are the same ?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yea exactly, so from my OP 'if the only difference, per structureID and per uniProtacc, is the chainID column, combine the chainID columns'; so in the sense that i'm not only combining based on uniProtacc, but also per structureID. I edited my question above to show an example; but I'm also going to try to think of how to edit your code (if possible) to fix this now.

Comment: I've had the idea should I make a new field which is UniProt accession + '_' + structureID, and then combine exactly using your code, but based on that new column, so then e.g. it would combine all the 'N0DKS8_6YC3' together and the 'N0DKS8_6YC4' together.

Comment: I did that, and it 99% works, am just going to update my question above to show something unusual that happens, if you had an idea.

Comment: I updated my question with Edit 2, I had suggested a possible reason why the issue was happening, but I'm actually not sure that's the reason anymore. I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: My bad, there was a mistake in the index ! Have a look at the update :)

Comment: You got there just ahead of me I just came back to say the same, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` inbuilt to perform item wise contatenation. `map` can can be use for further processing.

For given input -

```
item = [['A', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04'], ['B', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04']]

output=list(map(lambda t: t[0] if t[0]==t[1] else t[0]+","+t[1], list(zip(*a))))
```

The result is -

```
['A,B', '2.8', 'P00720', '37541.04']
```

Note: The lambda in `map` assumes that at max 2 rows are getting contaminated. You could easily change that for n as well.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately it's common for there to be more than two rows contaminated.